# AttributeError when attempting to access module functionality

Tags: python, module

I am writing a task that runs within [the invoke framework](http://www.pyinvoke.org/) :

```
from invoke import task

@task
def profitreport(ctx, ini=None):
    from lib import report
    report.profit.main(ini)
```

However, when I run the task I get the following error traceback:

```
schemelab@metta:~/prg/surgetrader/src$ invoke profitreport
Processing ini-mikegardner936@gmail.ini
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/schemelab/install/miniconda3/bin/invoke", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(program.run())
  File "/home/schemelab/install/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/invoke/program.py", line 293, in run
    self.execute()
  File "/home/schemelab/install/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/invoke/program.py", line 414, in execute
    executor.execute(*self.tasks)
  File "/home/schemelab/install/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/invoke/executor.py", line 129, in execute
    result = call.task(*args, **call.kwargs)
  File "/home/schemelab/install/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/invoke/tasks.py", line 115, in __call__
    result = self.body(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/schemelab/prg/surgetrader/src/tasks.py", line 43, in profitreport
    report.profit.main(ini)
AttributeError: module 'lib.report' has no attribute 'profit'
schemelab@metta:~/prg/surgetrader/src$
```

The main function definitely exists in `src/lib/report/profit.py` and I have `__init__.py` files all along the directory path, but for some reason it is not being invoked.

Here is the filesystem hierarchy:

```
  /home/schemelab/prg/surgetrader/src:
  total used in directory 19568 available 21885552
  drwxr-xr-x 8 schemelab schemelab     4096 Oct 14 19:05 .
  drwxr-xr-x 5 schemelab schemelab     4096 Oct 12 15:49 ..
  drwxr-xr-x 4 schemelab schemelab     4096 Oct 14 09:04 lib
  -rw-r--r-- 1 schemelab schemelab      910 Oct 14 09:10 tasks.py

  /home/schemelab/prg/surgetrader/src/lib:
  total used in directory 60 available 21885552
  drwxr-xr-x 4 schemelab schemelab 4096 Oct 14 09:04 .
  drwxr-xr-x 8 schemelab schemelab 4096 Oct 14 19:05 ..
  -rw-r--r-- 1 schemelab schemelab    1 Jul 15 02:26 __init__.py
  drwxr-xr-x 2 schemelab schemelab 4096 Oct 14 09:06 report

  /home/schemelab/prg/surgetrader/src/lib/report:
  total used in directory 16 available 21885552
  drwxr-xr-x 2 schemelab schemelab 4096 Oct 14 09:06 .
  drwxr-xr-x 4 schemelab schemelab 4096 Oct 14 09:04 ..
  -rw-r--r-- 1 schemelab schemelab    1 Oct 14 09:04 __init__.py
  -rw-r--r-- 1 schemelab schemelab 2379 Oct 14 09:06 profit.py
```

and here is `profit.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import configparser
import argh
import collections
import logging
from retry import retry
from db import db
import mybittrex
from bittrex.bittrex import SELL_ORDERBOOK
from pprint import pprint

def loop_forever():
    while True:
        pass


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def open_order(result):

    pprint(result['IsOpen'])
    return result['IsOpen']


def report_profit(config_file, b):
    import csv
    csv_file = "tmp/" + config_file + ".csv"
    csvfile = open(csv_file, 'w', newline='')
    fieldnames = 'sell_closed sell_opened market units_sold sell_price sell_commission units_bought buy_price buy_commission profit'.split()
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    csv_writer.writeheader()

    for buy in db().select(
        db.buy.ALL,
        orderby=~db.buy.timestamp
    ):


        if buy.config_file != config_file:
            #print("config file != {}... skipping".format(config_file))
            continue

        if len(buy.sell_id) < 12:
            #print("No sell id ... skipping")
            continue

        so = b.get_order(buy.sell_id)['result']

        if open_order(so):
            print("Open order ... skipping")
            continue

        pprint(buy)
        pprint(so)

        sell_proceeds = so['Price'] - so['CommissionPaid']

        bo = b.get_order(buy.order_id)['result']

        buy_proceeds = bo['Price'] + bo['CommissionPaid']

        pprint("sell_proceeds = {}. buy Order = {}. buy proceeds = {}".format(
            sell_proceeds, bo, buy_proceeds))

        profit = sell_proceeds - buy_proceeds

        calculations = {
            'sell_closed': so['Closed'],
            'sell_opened': so['Opened'],
            'market': so['Exchange'],
            'units_sold': so['Quantity'],
            'sell_price': so['PricePerUnit'],
            'sell_commission': so['CommissionPaid'],
            'units_bought': bo['Quantity'],
            'buy_price': bo['PricePerUnit'],
            'buy_commission': bo['CommissionPaid'],
            'profit': profit
        }

        csv_writer.writerow(calculations)


def main(ini):

    config_file = ini
    config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
    config.read(config_file)

    b = mybittrex.make_bittrex(config)
    report_profit(config_file, b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    argh.dispatch_command(main)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following importable packages/modules available:

- `lib`
- `lib.report`
- `lib.report.profit` (contains few functions)

In your task function, you import `lib.report`, but you access `lib.report.profit`, which is not imported. Hence, you get an error that `profit` is not there.

Python does not look into the filesystem on the function calls, but only on import. So it does not know that the `lib.report.profit` module exists when doing the `...main()` call.

Change it to the following:

```
from lib.report.profit import main
main(ini)
```

PS: It is a separate topic on the usage of the `main()` function for this purpose, but it is beyond the scope of the question of importing.